# need to print all rows

Tags: python, csv, brackets

```
for row in rows[:5]:
```

This will give me the first 5 rows.
lets say I have a thousands rows - how can I print them all - what should I use between the square brackets ?

I am trying to print all rows but I am looking for something that will print the whole file regardless how big it is by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write

```
for row in rows:
    ...
```

no need to apply a [slice](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/)

Comment: If this helped then you can accept it as the answer to close this question

Comment: need to wait 15 mins :) i tried to do it already